# Docker startup script cannot be found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker for Windows 10 to start up a eureka and configuration server. I'm trying to add startup script to ensure eureka has fully started before starting the config server. The following files are stored at the root of my project:

**Dockerfile - config server**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd && apk add curl
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/configserver
ADD ./target/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/configserver/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Waiting for the eureka server to start  on port $EUREKASERVER_PORT"
echo "********************************************************"
while ! `nc -z eurekaserver $EUREKASERVER_PORT`; do sleep 3; done
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>> Eureka Server has started"

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Starting Configuration Server
echo "********************************************************"
java -jar /usr/local/configserver/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Using the following docker-compose:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
    eurekaserver:
        image: eureka-naming-server
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
    configserver:
        image: config-server
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"
        environment:
            EUREKASERVER_PORT: 8761
            EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\docker\prj> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
Creating eureka-naming-server_configserver_1 ... done
Creating eureka-naming-server_eurekaserver_1 ... done
Attaching to eureka-naming-server_configserver_1, eureka-naming-server_eurekaserver_1
configserver_1  | /bin/sh: ./run.sh: not found
```

Any ideas as to why run.sh cannot be found?
Thanks

Comment: try using the absolute path to run.sh

Comment: I tried the absolute path but still getting the same result. I have also tried adding the script to a specific folder and calling it from there, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Windows 10 host, you say?  Are you sure your script has Unix line endings (there aren’t stray \r bytes in the file)?

Comment: @DavidMaze, that resolved my issue. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

My dear i think your problem is with this :

> ADD run.sh run.sh

you are trying to copy run.sh from your host machine to your docker image, ensure that run.sh exists in your project directory which is in your case it should be beside Dockerfile.

I've a running example like your case in my git repo :
https://github.com/iabughosh/microservices , develop branch, it is not merged to master yet.

Answer (score 0):

you don't specify the dockerfile in your docker-compose file. You need to remove the `image: xyz` and instead write `build: .` (assuming the dockerfile is on the same location as the docker-compose.yml)

As it is, your dockerfile is never even built

Comment: the docker-compose.yml file is in the parent directory so it can be used with both servers. I have updated my compose file per your suggestion (`build: ./eureka-naming-server` and `build: ./config-server`), but it still cannot find run.sh